# Remove directory structure from URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My website URL is currently like this:

- http://​ori123.com/product/category/9/0/case-apple

I want to change it into this:

- http://​ori123.com/case-apple

I tried the following code in my .htaccess file but it is not working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule http://ori123.com/rock-rotary-smart-case-series-for-ipad-air/(.*)/$ /product/detail/128/rock-rotary-smart-case-series-for-ipad-air?$1=
```

Can somebody tell me how can I do this using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

You only match `REQUEST_URI` in `RewriteRule` without protocol and domain name. Use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^rock-rotary-smart-case-series-for-ipad-air/(.*?)/?$ /product/detail/128/rock-rotary-smart-case-series-for-ipad-air?$1 [L]
```